# Is it safe to use the fontawesome script you get when signing up, or should I use the link from CDNJS?

Tags: font-awesome

After signing up for font awesome, I get a script like the one below, which I have to use to use fontawesome in my project. My concern is the censored part which is some numbers that I believe is personal to me. In the tutorial I watched, the creator censored that part aswell. Does this mean that it is unsafe to use this link in real projects because other people can copy my link and "use my account"?

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/[CENSORED].js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I also saw a tutorial using a link from CDNJS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

I am not familiar with CDNJS so I wonder if this is a safer option? Or what even is the difference in terms of what is more performant on a real site?

Answer (score 0):

CDN is safe to use and also its easy. you just need to go to their website and find CDN link and copy it in your project (version 6 does not support CDN and you have to use kit)

read this article to become familiar with kit, I think its safe and you should not be worry

[font awesome kit](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/setup/use-kit)